# What's the correct way to update a @ViewChild component on app load

Tags: angular, lifecycle, viewchild

I have a small Angular app which has a storage logic that should update a child component if there's something in it.

The way it's today is like the following:

```
export class HomeComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    @ViewChild(WidgetComponent)
    private widgetChild: WidgetComponent;
  
    constructor(private storageService: StorageService) {}
  
    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
      const widget = this.storageService.loadData();
      this.widgetChild.updateData(widget);
      this.cdr.detectChanges(); // Prevents error
    }
}
```

This logic is working fine as it's today but if I remove the line with comment I get the error:

> ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'undefined'. Current value: '[object Object]'.

This solution doesn't seem to be a good one to me, can somebody help me improve it?

Comment: correct way would be to pass data to your child components through input properties, rather than calling method. if it is not possible - leave it as it is in your example. i don't see any issues rather than just a little bit more performance consume on init

Comment: Why do you update the child component's data in the parent component ? The child component's data is loaded with your storage service but doesn't seem to be dependant from the parent component. You could simply load the data in the chid component ngOnInit.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. @Andrei response makes a lot of sense to me and that improved my code IMO.

FrançoisMinh Your solution is really good too but, I will use the same component somewhere else too and this logic might conflict with it.

Thank you :)